# Can't browse or/and debug local asp.net web-site. w3wp.exe not launched

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, debugging, iis

We have some released ASP.NET project and now we are supporting it. I installed Windows 8.1 on my macMini and cloned that project. The webSite works on server normally and locally on machines of other developers. IIS configured as well. When i trying to browse webSite from IIS manager I have the following problem in chrome:

> This webpage is not available
>        ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

When i try to debug via Visual Studio by pressing the debug button i have this:

> Unable to start debugging on the web server. The debugger cannot
>   connect to the remote computer. The debugger was unable to resolve the
>   specified computer name.

But i think it's ok, cause we are debugging this project pressing Ctrl+Alt+P and attaching to w3wp.exe process, but it's not launched. Actually this should be launched automatically, as i know.

> Windows 8.1; MSVS 2015; .NET 4.5.1;

I tried to restart IIS. And i configured binding to my website with host name myWebsiteName and port 80.

Update 11.6.2015 :
And one more thing! The default web site works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running as Administrator? Also try these commands:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /renew
ipconfig /registerdns
```

from the command-line (running as Administrator)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, i'm running as Administrator. A ran those commands. The result you can see in the link 
[here](https://screencloud.net/v/kGu1)

. And it has the same behaviour. Not browsing and w3wp.exe process not runned